# Compare two NSArrays and return number of differences

Tags: objective-c, compare, nsarray

How can I take two NSArrays, compare them, then return the number of differences, preferably the number of different objects, for example:

Array 1:
    one
    two
    three

Array 2:
    two
    four
    one

I would like that to return "1"

Comment: Why is that one difference and not two?

Comment: because there's one element that's different.  1 has "three" and 2 has "four"

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can do this by using an intermediate [NSMutableArray](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
NSArray *array1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"One", @"Two", @"Three", nil];
NSArray *array2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Two", @"Four", @"One", nil];
NSMutableArray *intermediate = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array1];
[intermediate removeObjectsInArray:array2];
NSUInteger difference = [intermediate count];
```

With that way, only common elements will be removed.

Comment: If you have a relatively large # of items in the array this *might* be slow. Maybe.  Measure it.  If it is, considering using `NSSet` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I found that the answer above didn't take arrays of differing size into account. If you do it as above, you should check to see which array.count is smaller and

```
[largerArray removeObjectsInArray:shorterArray];
```

OR

I made them both NSSets and then compared.

```
[set1 isEqualToSet:set2];
```

That way size and order are both dealt with properly! (I didn't need to know the number of differences)